# Binary Search Tree, one test does not go through

Tags: java, junit

I have written a code of Binary Search tree that extends comparable and implements an interface. The code for leaves and the helper method countLeaves (included down here), makes sure that all of the test goes through except for one, heightIsLogOfNumLeavesTreeIsPerfect().

// TODO: Look at the Leaves and the helper method to leaves and see how I should change it so that this test goes through aswell.

//EDIT: I have added the whole tree class

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: <2>
     but: was <0>
Expected :<2>
Actual   :<0>
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.Timeout;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
/**
 * Test class for a tree.
 */
public class TreeTest{
    @Rule public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(5);

    Tree<Integer> tree;
    int[] elementsInTree;
    int[] elementsNotInTree;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        /**
         * This tree should look like this:
         *
         *               8
         *             /  \
         *            3   10
         *           / \    \
         *          1   6    14
         *             / \   /
         *            4   7 13
         */
        tree = new Tree<>();
        elementsInTree = new int[] {8, 10, 14, 13, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7};
        for (int elem : elementsInTree) {
            tree.insert(elem);
        }
        elementsNotInTree = new int[] {34, -3, -10, 12, 74, 5};
    }

    @Test
    public void heightIsLogOfNumLeavesTreeIsPerfect() {
        // For a perfect tree, tree.height() == log2(tree.leaves()

        // Arrange
        Tree<Integer> tree = new Tree<>();
        int[] elements = new int[] {8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 9, 14};
        int numLeaves = 4;
        int logNumLeaves = (int) Math.round(Math.log(numLeaves) / Math.log(2));
        for (int elem : elements) {
            tree.insert(elem);
        }

        // Act
        int height = tree.height();
        // Assert
        assertThat(height, equalTo(logNumLeaves));
    }
}
```

```
**
 * An interface describing a generic Comparable
 */

public interface BSTInterface <T>{

    boolean search(T elem);
   
    boolean insert(T elem);

        int size();

    int height();
   
    int leaves();
}
```

```
/**
 * An Binary Search tree implementation of the comparable interface.
 * @param <T>
 */
public class Tree <T extends Comparable <T>> implements BSTInterface <T>{
    private int size;
    private Node root;
    public class Node{
        private Node Left;
        private Node Right;
        private T data;

        public Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
        }
        public Node getRight(){
            return Right;
        }

        public Node getLeft() {
            return Left;
        }

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
    public Tree (){
        size = 0;
        root = null;
    }


    /**
     * Test for presence of a value.
     * @param elem
     * @return true/false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean search(T elem) {
        if(root == null ||elem == null){
        return false;
        }
        Node node = root;
        while(true){
            if(node.data.compareTo(elem) > 0){
                if(node.Right == null){
                    return false;
                } else{
                    node = node.Right;
                }
            } else if(node.data.compareTo(elem) == 0){
                break;
            } else{
                if(node.Left== null){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    node = node.Left;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Add value to tree; duplicates are not allowed.
     * Return true if the element is not already present (and is thus inserted),
     * false otherwise.
     *
     * @param elem
     * @return true/false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean insert(T elem) {
        if (elem == null){
            return false;
        }
        if (root == null){
            root = new Node(elem);
            size++;
            return true;
        }
        Node node = root;
        while (true){
            if (node.data.compareTo(elem) > 0) {
                if (node.Right == null){
                    node.Right = new Node(elem);
                    size++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = node.Right;
                }

            } else if (node.data.compareTo(elem) == 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (node.Left == null){
                    node.Left = new Node(elem);
                    size++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    node = node.Left;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * the number of elements in the tree
     * @return size.
     */
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * The height of the tree.
     * The empty tree and the tree with only the root node both have height 0.
     * @return the height of the tree.
     */
    @Override
    public int height() {
        return countHeight(root);
    }
    /**
     * Helper method for height
     */
    private int countHeight(Node node){
        if(node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return Math.max(countHeight(node.Left), countHeight(node.Right));
    }

    /**
     * The number of leaves in the tree.
     * @return the amount of leaves the tree have.
     */
    @Override
    public int leaves() {
        return countLeaves(root);
    }
    /**
     * Helper method for leaves
     */
    private int countLeaves(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (node.Left == null && node.Right == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return countLeaves(node.Left) + countLeaves(node.Right);
    }


    /**
     * A string describing the tree
     * @return
     */
    public String toString(){
        String str = "[" + helpToString(root);
        if (str.length() > 1) {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 2);
        } return str + "]";
    }

    /**
     * Helper method for toString
     */
    private String helpToString(Node node) {
        String str = "";
        if (node != null) {
            str += helpToString(node.Right);
            str += node.data + ", ";
            str += helpToString(node.Left);
        }
        return str;
      }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you actually calculating height and not leaf count?
Anyway, this tree's height is still certainly not zero. Is `height` method just `return 0` stub for now?

Also the input tree is by no way perfect, so this test is conceptually incorrect.

Comment: @KarashevichB. How should i improve the tree according to you? Also I have edited so the whole tree class is included

Comment: `countHeight(Node node)` will only traverse to the end of all nodes and return 0 when it reaches the end(ie `node==null`), you're not actually counting the height. You need to have an integer value that increases based on the number of nodes it goes through before it hits the end of a particular branch and this will return through recursively and give you the proper max height using `Math.max`.

Comment: Nevermind, I was looking at the setup section. The tree in the test itself looks fine. Why do you even have setup in this test? The data it sets doesn't seem to be used at all.

Comment: @KarashevichB. I have changed my code,  private int countHeight(Node node){
        if(node == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return Math.max(countHeight(node.Left)+1, countHeight(node.getRight())+1);
    } but now one test called heightIsZeroWhenTreeIsEmpty() is not going through

Comment: oh so you had that defined in another way huh... ok then, just add another `if` in `height` before calling `countHeight(root)`, that should cover it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `countHeight` method can return either zero or a maximum of two returns, and there are no other operations in it. You can't get a value greater of zero out of zeros just by using max function.

You should return -1 for an empty tree and `max(height(left) + 1, height(right) + 1)` otherwise. Each +1 accounts for length of corresponding parent-child edge.

(Mathematically speaking, height of an "empty" tree is usually undefined, but defining it as -1 in this case helps a lot so let's stick to that.)